# has_archive=false on the default post type

Tags: posts, archives

On the default `post` type, why does the `has_archive` property equals to `FALSE`?

```
$type_obj = get_post_type_object('post');
var_dump($type_obj->has_archive); // FALSE
```

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to have archive for posts. FALSE is set by default to all post types.

Comment: Posts have archives, they are displayed on the homepage with a fresh install.

Comment: **has_archive** Enables post type archives. Will use $post_type as archive slug by default. Default: false
Note: Will generate the proper rewrite rules if rewrite is enabled. Also use rewrite to change the slug used. _It means that there should be archive with slug http:://mysite.com/post/ - do you have such archive?_

Comment: Got it, `has_archive` should have been named `has_archive_slug`. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Late answer*.

---

`has_archive` applies only for the `rewrite` arguments.

#### In Detail

If `has_archive` is set to `true`, then the `$archive_slug` will get set to the `rewrite['slug']` argument. If then a `rewrite['with_front']` arg is set, then this one will get prepended. The result of this will then get added as rewrite rule:

> ```
> add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type", 'top' );
> ```

If `feeds` are set to true and `has_archive` also, then you'll also get rewritten rules for feeds:

> ```
> add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/feed/$feeds/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&feed=$matches[1]', 'top' );
> add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/$feeds/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&feed=$matches[1]', 'top' );
> ```

The same principle applies for `rewrite['pages']`:

> ```
> add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/{$wp_rewrite->pagination_base}/([0-9]{1,})/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
> ```

#### Summed up:

If you ain't got `has_archive` set to `true`, then any try to add rewrites for `feeds`, `pages` or archives will end up with a big **`?`**.

Comment: With `has_archive` to `false` you are able to use a custom page as archive.