# Custom Post Type get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) returns false

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, url-rewriting

Permalinks are (finally) working for individual posts of the custom `yoga-event` type I've created.

And archive works without URL rewriting:

`http://website.localhost/?post_type=yoga-event`

However `get_post_type_archive_link( 'yoga-event' )` returns false.

This is the array I'm sending to `register_post_type`:

```
Array
(
        [labels] => Array
                (
                        [name] => Yoga Events
                        [singular_name] => Yoga Event
                        [menu_name] => Yoga Events
                        [all_items] => Yoga Events
                        [add_new] => Add New
                        [add_new_item] => Add New Yoga Event
                        [edit_item] => Edit Yoga Event
                        [new_item] => New Yoga Event
                        [view_item] => View Yoga Event
                        [search_items] => Search Yoga Events
                        [not_found] => No Yoga Events found
                        [not_found_in_trash] => No Yoga Events found in Trash
                        [parent_item_colon] => Parent Yoga Event:
                )

        [public] => 1
        [rewrite] => Array
                (
                        [slug] => yoga-event
                )

        [has_arhchive] => 1
        [menu_icon] => dashicons-book-alt
)
```

I can sort of make my own "archive" like this:

```
$type = 'yoga-event';
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    $my_query->the_post(); 
    ?>

        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> </a></p>

    <?php

    endwhile;
} // list of yoga-event items
```

But I'm guessing that the array that `register_post_type` is getting has some kind of misconfiguration.

Any insights?

PS:

```
//List Post Types
foreach ( get_post_types( '', 'names' ) as $post_type ) {
     echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
}
```

Returns `yoga-event` (among others).

Comment: there's a typo here- `has_arhchive`, is that also in your code?

Comment: good eyes, man. that was the problem (at the end of a long line of others). Want to post answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I see your `register_post_type` line? Those are usually like: `register_post_type( 'some-post-type', $args );`.

In this example, `some-post-type` would be the ID that you use in `get_post_type_archive_link( 'some-post-type' )`, not the rewrite slug `yoga-event`.

Comment: no. i should probably have specified the first argument, but it matched the post returned by `get_post_types`

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the code above, which one of the community pointed out, but I'll add here that that final piece of the puzzle for me was this little bit of code ([also SO-based](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54357/has-archive-false-on-the-default-post-type)) by which we can examine a CPT as WP understands (outputs) it:

```
$type = 'yoga-event';
//let's look at our CPT:    
$type_obj = get_post_type_object($type);
mz_pr($type_obj);

function mz_pr($message) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($message);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Also this wonderful [CPT Class](https://github.com/jjgrainger/wp-custom-post-type-class) is being a great way to generate the CPT. (Note, though that I am currently adding ``` 'has_archive' => True`` to the ```register_post_types` array manually, as the method for adding it via an "instance method" didn't seem to be working.)